# Stream edit text file and replace string with increments

Tags: node.js, bash, awk, text, markdown

I want to duplicate markdown files to ~200 files and replace some strings in the document with incrementing changes. How should i do this? I am a new web developer, and my familiarity is just so-so with PHP and Node.js, but decent Linux user. I am thinking of using `sed` but can't wrap my mind around it.

Let's say i want to duplicate:

```
post.md    "this is post _INCREMENT_"
```

then I run:

```
run generate "post.md" --number 2
```

to generate:

```
post1.md    "this is post 1"
post2.md    "this is post 2"
```

Comment: From my point of view, `sed` is unsuitable because it cannot count. I would recommend `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `-number 2` option?

Comment: to increment 2 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining `sed` and `bash`, would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# show usage on improper arguments
usage() {
    echo "usage: $1 filename.md number"
    exit 1
}

file=$1                         # obtain filename
[[ -n $file ]] || usage "$0"    # filename is not specified
num=$2 || usage "$0"            # obtain end bumber
(( num > 0 )) || usage "$0"     # number is not specified or illegal

for (( i = 1; i <= num; i++ )); do
    new="${file%.md}$i.md"      # new filename with the serial number
    cp -p -- "$file" "$new"     # duplicate the file
    sed -i "s/_INCREMENT_/$i/" "$new"
                                # replace "_INCREMENT_" with the serial number
done
```

Save the script above as a file `generate` or whatever, then run:

```
bash generate post.md 2
```